# Issue in CSS layout

Tags: html, css

In my CSS layout I have given dimension and background color to div and i wanted to paste image over it but due to some reason after doing that the div box is collapsing.

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #534;
}

div {
    display: block;
    max-width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
} 
.box { 
    background: url('img/mike.png') no-repeat center; 
}
```

Comment: `background` overwrite `background-color` too. use `background-image` instead.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh you should add it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background` overrides `background-color` too. use `background-image` instead. Use this:

```
.box { 
    background-image: url('img/mike.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hpzowbj/)

Comment: I just wanted to write in short. why it is making difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` is not actually collapsing, just removing the `background-color` as `background` overrides it.
Try using this for the `background` CSS declaration:

```
background: #534 url('img/mike.png') no-repeat center;
```